# center vertically a ul li list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, center

I try to center vertically the `li`element of a `ul` navigation.
Some of the elements inside the `li` have different heights, and I can't find the solution :/

http://jsfiddle.net/uLgcu/8/

The HTML :

```
 <ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#" >Test</a></li>  
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div id="logo">
                THE BIG DIV
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" >Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS :

```
#navigation li {
display: inline ;
font-size: 17px ;
margin-left : 15px;
float : left ;
background-color : red;

 }

#logo {
width : 300px;
height : 300px;
background-color : blue;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: `#navigation {line-height: 300px;}` ?

Comment: So you want those small elements to be next to the *big div* but also be centered vertically?  So they kind of float along the side of it I guess?

Comment: Thanks Jaa-c ! But line-height works only for text; and i have an image in the big div... http://jsfiddle.net/uLgcu/8/ Sorry, i haven't precise !

Comment: So line-height doesn't do what you want... but you've updated your question to include a fiddle with line-height?   I'm really confused as to what you're asking here.  Please try and describe exactly the effect you are looking for.   Even better, if you could give a "picture" of some sort to show how you want the elements laid out, we might be able to help.   But with the info you're giving, this is just confusing.

Comment: As @Charlie74 said line height, you just need to add vertical-align: middle; to the image. http://jsfiddle.net/uLgcu/14/

Comment: Thanks both of you ! And sorry @Charlie74 if i wasn't clear enough !

Answer (score -1):

```
#navigation li img{
/*
display: inline ;
font-size: 17px ;
margin-left : 15px;
float : left ;
background-color : red;
*/
vertical-align:middle;
 }
```